# Extracting content BETWEEN a regex python?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, matching, text-extraction

Is there a simple method to pull content between a regex?  Assume I have the following sample text

```
 SOME TEXT [SOME MORE TEXT] value="ssss" SOME MORE TEXT
```

My regex is:

```
 compiledRegex = re.compile('\[.*\] value=("|\').*("|\')')
```

This will obviously return the entire [SOME MORE TEXT] value="ssss", however I only want ssss to be returned since that's what I'm looking for

I can obviously define a parser function but I feel as if python provides some simple pythonic way to do such a task

Comment: Your regular expression is faulty. It'll match `value="foo'` and `value='bar"` which you almost certainly don't want to do. You should use this instead: `r'''\[.*\] value=("|')(.*?)\1'''`. Note that using a triple-quoted string obviates the need to escape the "'". Also, it's a good idea to always use raw strings (e.g. r'foo' and r"bar") when dealing with regular expressions in Python.

Answer (score 2):

This is what capturing groups are designed to do.

```
compiledRegex = re.compile('\[.*\] value=(?:"|\')(.*)(?:"|\')') 
matches = compiledRegex.match(sampleText)
capturedGroup = matches.group(1) # grab contents of first group
```

The `?:` inside the old groups (the parentheses) means that the group is now a *non-capturing* group; that is, it won't be accessible as a group in the result. I converted them to keep the output simpler, but you can leave them as capturing groups if you prefer (but then you have to use `matches.group(2)` instead, since the first quote would be the first captured group).

Answer (score 0):

Your original regex is too greedy: `r'.*\]'` won't stop at the first `']'` and the second `'.*'` won't stop at `'"'`. To stop at `c` you could use `[^c]` or `'.*?'`:

```
regex = re.compile(r"""\[[^]]*\] value=("|')(.*?)\1""")
```

#### Example

```
m = regex.search("""SOME TEXT [SOME MORE TEXT] value="ssss" SOME MORE TEXT""")
print m.group(2)
```